# Icon appears on screen without specifying in android manifest file.

Tags: android, android-activity, android-icons

I have not specified `android:icon` attribute in `<activity>` tag. Still somehow icon appears on screen for that activity. 
My problem is that how to prevent icon from appearing in this activity?
The strange thing is that in other activities icon does not appear(this is what I want for all activity).

Comment: "how to prevent icon from appearing in this activity" -- appear *where*? In the action bar?

Comment: Why are you asking too many question for same?

Comment: @PankajKumar sorry for this. But I'm looking from different angles of my problem and don't want to discuss all aspects in a single question.

Comment: Ok no problem. Choice is yours

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in `<application>` tag `icon` attribute was used which becomes the bydefault icon of all activities, unless explicity specified.
In activities where icon was not appearing, title bar was disabled and thus icon that is a part of title bar does not get displayed.